# Convert Python Post request with payload and files to ansible uri module

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, python-requests

I need to convert python request below :

```
response = requests.post(url, files=files, data = payload, auth = (idrac_username, idrac_password), verify=False)
```

where

```
filename = file.cer
ImageLocation = /tmp
ImagePath = os.path.join(ImageLocation, filename)
url = 'https://10.10.10.2/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/SecureBoot/Certificates/DB/'
payload = {"CertificateType": SHA256}
files = {'text':(None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'),'file': (filename, open(ImagePath, 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')}
idrac_username = user
idrac_password = password
```

to Ansible URI Module
Making sure that data and files are included

And here what i've tried

```
    tasks:
         - name: Set Certificate to DB
           uri:            
             url:   https://10.10.10.2/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/SecureBoot/Certificates/DB/
             method: POST
             body_format: form-multipart
             user: "{{ username }}"
             password: "{{ password }}"
             force_basic_auth: yes
             validate_certs: no
             headers:
                     Accept: '*/*'
             body:
                file1:
                    filename:  PNE.der
                    mime_type: application/octet-stream
                file2:
                    filename:  head.json
                    mime_type: application/json
```

And I got Error 500

```
fatal: [r640]: FAILED! => {"access_control_allow_origin": "*", "cache_control": "no-cache", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_length": "596", "content_type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;charset=utf-8", "date": "Wed, 12 Jan 2022 11:02:12 GMT", "elapsed": 1, "json": {"error": {"@Message.ExtendedInfo": [{"Message": "The requested SecureBoot Certificate Import operation cannot be completed.", "MessageArgs": [], "MessageArgs@odata.count": 0, "MessageId": "IDRAC.2.1.SWC9004", "RelatedProperties": [], "RelatedProperties@odata.count": 0, "Resolution": "Enter valid parameters and retry the operation. If the issue persists, free some space in the certificate store by deleting few certificates, restart iDRAC, and then retry the operation.", "Severity": "Critical"}], "code": "Base.1.5.GeneralError", "message": "A general error has occurred. See ExtendedInfo for more information"}}, "msg": "Status code was 500 and not [200]: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error", "odata_version": "4.0", "redirected": false, "server": "Apache", "status": 500, "strict_transport_security": "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload", "url": "https://10.10.10.2/redfish/v1/Systems/System.Embedded.1/SecureBoot/Certificates/DB/", "x_frame_options": "DENY"}
```

Comment: Where is the ansible task you started to write ? What have you tried ? What is not working as expected ? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70689133/edit) your question to add those details.

Comment: I've added that , please check